# WithEvent in Class module not getting variable from Let Property in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, class

I think I'm missing something simple here.  Trying to use a variable in a Class module.  Let and Get work fine.  But if I try to use the variable in a different sub in the Class module I just get a value of 0.

Class Module clsCombobox

```
Public WithEvents ComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Public WithEvents ComboTextBox As MSForms.TextBox

Public Num As Long

Public Property Let Number(Value As Long)
    Num = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = Num
End Property

Private Sub ComboBox_Change()
    Me.ComboTextBox.Value = Num
    'this gives value of 0
End Sub
```

Userform Module

```
Dim obEvents as clsCombobox
Set obEvents = New clsCombobox
obEvents.Number = 52
MsgBox obEvents.Number 'this prints 52
```

Sub that sets ComboBox

```
Private Sub GroupCombobox()
Dim i As Long
Dim obEvents As clsCombobox

Set collCombobox = New Collection

For i = 1 To 5
    Set obEvents = New clsCombobox
    Set obEvents.ComboBox = Me.Controls("cbAbility" & i)
    Set obEvents.ComboTextBox = Me.Controls("tbAbility" & i & "Text")
    collCombobox.Add obEvents
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: For proper encapsulation, `Num` should be a `Private` field.

Comment: Can you share the code that sets `ComboBox` and `ComboTextBox`?

Comment: Added the code.  The ComboBox_Change sub works well if I set it to `= 52` or `= Me.ComboBox.ListIndex`.  It's something about getting that variable.

Comment: who/from where is calling `ComboBox_Change`?

Comment: ComboBox_Change is just the event when you select any option in the dropdown list of one of the comboboxes in the collection

Comment: The combobox is on a userform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you ever set the value. I assume you mean to do that in the loop? Perhaps not with the value of `i`, but here you can see the idea...

```
For i = 1 To 5
    Set obEvents = New clsCombobox

    'Set the value here
    obEvents.Number = 52 ' 52 or whatever is needed as Number

    Set obEvents.ComboBox = Me.Controls("cbAbility" & i)
    Set obEvents.ComboTextBox = Me.Controls("tbAbility" & i & "Text")
    collCombobox.Add obEvents
Next i
```

Comment: The `i` is just for the loop to add a number of controls to the collection.  So `cbAbility1`, `cbAbility2` are different comboboxes.  The class allows them all to act the same way when you select something in their dropdown list.

Comment: @bigbucky Maybe you simply forgot obEvents.Number = 52 inside of the for i=1 to 5 loop? When you don't set the Number then it will still have value of zero. @thuderframe you mean `Number` not `Value`?

Comment: I see. I did t realize I had to set it for each control. I thought once you set the variable it would stay set in the Class module. I’m away from computer but will try later.

Comment: No, each object is independent from the other objects, it is different memory location, each object hast its own state and data etc.

Comment: The class module is like a template for the objects which is created at design time. At runtime the objects are created based on this template and each object is isolated, lives in another memory location.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I think I understand now.  Putting it in the loop worked.